# jquery: fancybox thumbnail helper, how to specify source?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, thumbnails, helper

I am using fancyBox 2, and I am using the "thumbnail helper."  When I have images in my gallery, fancyBox automatically uses the target images for thumbnails, but when I link to a video (Vimeo, in my case), it does not generate a thumbnail.  I thought this would be easily remedied by just specifying an image for fancyBox to use for the video link, but I don't know how to do this.

On the website, http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/, it says that there is a "source" option for the thumbnail helper, which should be used like this to enable thumbnails, and set source:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers:  {
        thumbs : {
            source : 'img/~~~.jpg'
        }
    }
});
```

But of course, that can't work, because how could I specify which thumbnail to use for which target image or video?  I can't find any working examples of the thumbnail helper being used with videos, or custom thumbnails. Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT:

The "source" option is described as a "function to obtain the URL of the thumbnail image".  I am trying to figure out how to use it.  I am thinking of something like

```
source: item.thum
```

where I have a "thum" attribute for the thumbnail source in each item that I am referencing, such as

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {href : 'image1.jpg', thum : 'thumb1.jpg'},
    {href : 'image2.jpg', thum : 'thumb2.jpg'},
    {href : 'image3.jpg', thum : 'thumb3.jpg'}],
    {helpers : {
        thumbs:{source:this.thum}
    }   }
)
```

Would it be something like this?  Can you see what I mean?  How would I actually make that work? As you can see, I am not a speaker of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work like this: my function found all items whose `href` element contained the string `http://vimeo`, and replaced those entire `href`s with the url of the thumbnail image I am using for the videos.

I had to learn about regular expressions, too, to make it work.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        thumbs : {
            source: function( item ) {
                return item.href.replace(/http:\/\/vimeo.*/gi, 'img/vimeo.jpg');
    },
});
```

Actually, I also have an HTML file in an iFrame in my gallery as well, and I wanted to give that its own thumbnail, too, so my final product was:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        thumbs : {
            source: function( item ) {
                return item.href.replace(/http:\/\/vimeo.*/gi, 'img/vimeo.jpg')
                .replace(/.*html/gi, 'img/html.jpg');
    },
});
```

For anyone who finds this thread, and wants to see an example of this in practice, [here is a link](http://www.studiogh.com) to the site where I used it.

Answer (score 1):

For different thumbs for different iframes (vimeo, youtube, etc.) I ended up doing this. More or less your original plan:

```
$.fancybox.open([
  { 
    href : 'photo.jpg',
    thumb : 'photo-thumb.jpg'
  }
], {
    helpers : {
      thumbs : {
        source : function( item ) {
          if (item.thumb) {
            return item.thumb;
          } else {
            return item.href;
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers:  {
        thumbs : {
          source : function ( item ) {
            return "/url/to/img.ext"; //get the image url for thumbnail
          }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is almost what I needed.